# Invalid property value CSS fit-content

Tags: css, web, cross-browser

I want to make my following CSS code cross-browser (Chrome & Fireofx) but it is not working:

```
width: fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;
height: fit-content;
height: -moz-fit-content;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Include the relevant html and css and tell us what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: check this : https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content